# How to automate generating input for script paths when number of variables changes between inputs

Tags: bash, shell, loops, for-loop

I have a variables.txt file containing a list of variable names like this:

```
Target  Location    Control_A   Control_B   Control_C   
Sample_A    City    Bos_1   Bos_2   Bos_3
Sample_B    Countryside Rno_1   Rno2
Sample_C    City    Cat_1
```

I need to use these details to create a list of commands that I can submit to a script that uses these variable names as information in this format:

```
./script.sh -target /path/to/Target -location /path/to/Location -controls /path/to/Control_A,/path/to/Control_B,/path/to/Control_C -outdir /path/to/outdir
```

Usually I would define my variables in the terminal such that for example:

```
Path_to_data="/home/user/data/"
Target="Sample_A"
Control_A="Rno_1"
Control_B="Rno_2"
```

etc

And then I would submit the command with the variable names, for example:

```
./script.sh -target /$Path_to_data/"$Target"_data/"$Target -Location /$Path_to_data/$Location -controls /$Path_to_data/$Control_A,/$Path_to_data/$Control_B
```

The problem is that now I have >100 jobs to submit so this approach is not feasible.

I would like a script or loop to read through the variables.txt file and for each row output a line to a new output.txt file where each line is a complete command input for ./script.sh

A crucial problem is I don't know how to automate it because  the number of Controls varies from Sample to Sample. So I can't just simply assign the columns Control_A, Control_B and Control_C as variables and print them and their paths as comma separated values for the -controls part of the ./script.sh input because sometimes there will only be one or two Controls depending on the row in the variables.txt file.

The output.txt would look like:

```
./script.sh -target /home/user/data/SampleA_data/Sample_A -Location /home/user/data/City -controls /home/user/data/Bos_1,/home/user/data/Bos_2,/home/user/data/Bos_3
./script.sh -target /home/user/data/SampleB_data/Sample_B -Location /home/user/data/Countryside -controls /home/user/data/Rno_1,/home/user/data/Rno2
./script.sh -target /home/user/data/SampleC_data/Sample_C -Location /home/user/data/City -controls /home/user/data/Cat_1
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: The separator in your variables.txt file is a single tabulation, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

prefix=/home/user/data/
while read -r target location ctrla ctrlb ctrlc; do
  [ -n "$ctrlb" ] && ctrlb=",${prefix}${ctrlb}"
  [ -n "$ctrlc" ] && ctrlc=",${prefix}${ctrlc}"

  printf './script.sh -target %s -Location %s -controls %s\n'\
    "${prefix}${target}"\
    "${prefix}${location}"\
    "${prefix}${ctrla}${ctrlb}${ctrlc}"

done < <(tail -n+2 variables.txt) > output.txt
```

I'm assuming that `Target`, `Location` and `Control_A` are always set. Only `Control_B` and `Control_C` are optional.

The `tail -n+2` is used to skip the header line of `variables.txt`. Your example `target` output looks a bit different (`.../SampleA_data/Sample_A`) and I'm not how you want it. Change this part as needed.

Example output:

```
$ cat output.txt
./script.sh -target /home/user/data/Sample_A -Location /home/user/data/City -controls /home/user/data/Bos_1,/home/user/data/Bos_2,/home/user/data/Bos_3
./script.sh -target /home/user/data/Sample_B -Location /home/user/data/Countryside -controls /home/user/data/Rno_1,/home/user/data/Rno2
./script.sh -target /home/user/data/Sample_C -Location /home/user/data/City -controls /home/user/data/Cat_1
```